# Can't focus input inside qtip inside bootstrap modal

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, qtip2

I have a button inside of a bootstrap modal that displays a tooltip via qtip2.  Inside the tooltip is an input element.  I can't get the input to focus while the modal is open.

Here is my plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/dByd0u?p=preview

HTML:

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyModal">Modal</button>

  <div id="qtip-content" style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="MyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
              <h2 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Bootstrap Modal</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" ng-init="modalLoad = true">
            <button qtip="">Show qtip</button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Did you get it solved? i'm experiencing exactly same issue after upgrading to jqueryui 1.11 and jquery 2.1

Comment: I never figured it out.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone still interested in a solution for this, simply remove `tabindex="-1"` attribute from your modal div. This is a hack to specifically prevent focusing on elements.

Comment: Or you can also increase the z-index of the element

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#qtip-content').find('input').focus();
});
```